# How can you make an MUI select field with some appended text that does not affect the field value

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, material-table

I want to make a select field which looks like this [image: desired outcome]

The only success I have had is to add `rows` as an end adornment, but this is only covered by the arrow icon and it is not clickable. [image: current outcome]

What adjustments can I make to my select field to append Rows to the field, but prevent the word from appearing in the options list or affecting the field values.

```
<Select id="row_select" value={rowsPerPage} onChange={onChangeRowsPerPage}>
    {rowsPerPageOptions.map((x, i) => (
        <MenuItem value={x} key={i}>
            {x}
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`TablePagination` has an attribute called `rowsPerPageOptions` dedicated to manipulate this select field.
It accepts either an array of numbers, or an array of specific objects with `value` and `label` keys.

```
<TablePagination
  rowsPerPageOptions={[
    { label: "5 rows", value: 5 },
    { label: "10 rows", value: 10 },
    { label: "25 rows", value: 25 },
    { label: "All", value: -1 },
  ]}
  //other props
/>
```

You can read the documentations [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#custom-pagination-options).

Comment: There has been a misunderstanding.  It seems I included too much unnecessary information originally in the question.  I have updated the question to better reflect my problem.

Comment: @CiaranCrowley so to be clear you want the options in the options list to be like "5","10",... with no appending text. But when user selected them, he can see the selected option + "rows". Am I right?

Comment: Yes, when a user has clicked on the select, he options should only be 5, 10, 15.  After selecting an option, the field should then contain their selection + rows

Comment: @CiaranCrowley I researched a lot but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to achieve the thing you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `InputProps` to customize the select drop-down. In there you can use `sx` prop to add some space between `svg drop down icon` and `text`.(In material ui V5)

See the below code, It will explain every thing more simply.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';

const rows = [
  {
    value: '25',
    label: '25',
  },
  {
    value: '20',
    label: '20',
  },
  {
    value: '10',
    label: '10',
  },
  {
    value: '4',
    label: '4',
  },
];

export default function SelectTextFields() {
  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <div>
        
      <TextField
         
          id="filled-start-adornment"
         
          select
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: <InputAdornment  sx={{width:"100px"}} position="start">rows</InputAdornment>,
          }}
         
        >
          {rows.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
          
            </TextField>
      </div>

    
    </Box>
  );
}
```

If you need to play with the code, [Use this sandbox url](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-adorment-select-o4le5y) and feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Answer (score -1):

To create a `select` field in JavaScript with appended text that does not affect the field value, you can use the `append()` method to add a new element to the end of the `select` field's container element. This new element can be a `span` or `label` element that contains the appended text, and it can be styled to look like it is part of the `select` field.

For example, you can use the following code to create a `select` field and append some text to it:

```js
// Create a select field
var select = document.createElement("select");

// Add options to the select field
var option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.value = "value1";
option1.text = "Option 1";
select.appendChild(option1);

var option2 = document.createElement("option");
option2.value = "value2";
option2.text = "Option 2";
select.appendChild(option2);

// Append some text to the select field
var text = document.createElement("span");
text.innerHTML = "Text to append";
text.style.color = "gray";
select.appendChild(text);

// Add the select field to the page
document.body.appendChild(select);
```

This code will create a `select` field with two options, and it will append the text "Text to append" to the end of the `select` field. The text will be displayed in gray to indicate that it is not part of the actual `select` field. When the user selects an option from the `select` field, the appended text will not affect the field's value.

Comment: I don't think you can have anything other than option elements (or optgroup) as children of a select element - your code will create 'llegal' HTML. See the technical summary in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example